# declaration Js file in another Js file

Tags: javascript, php

I have question. I have

1. date.js (for datetime manipulation)
2. control.js (for general controls in forms)

And I want declare in control.js -> date.js 
to use datetime function in some controls.

**So, is possible declare one js file in another?**

Thanks for reply.

Comment: If you mean using the functions from date.js inside control.js - it is possible, BUT it has to be loaded before control.js. The functions have to be available ( declared ) before they are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding the statement you have mentioned in the top of my .js file.

```
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="file2.js" ></scr'+'ipt>');
```

but why are you **include?** You don't need an **include**. You can **just add the code** to the **existing JavaScript file**. Or you can call **js** files from the HTML file.

Comment: thx for all of U, this works fine. Maybe another works too, but I am begginer in PHP so this is simply.

Answer (score 0):

you can use js to dynamically load other javascript files.

and there're lots of libraries out there doing this.

One of my favorite is https://github.com/chriso/load.js

```
load('date.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your code either in the AMD or in the commonJS module format.
For AMD there's [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/), and for commonJS there is [browserify](http://browserify.org/). You can also check out [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/motivation.html), which supports both.

I've made very good experiences with browserify, since it lets you use loads of nodejs modules so you can use `npm` to install them. It's a great tool. I've also heard lots of good things about webpack, so maybe try it out. It allows you to even bundle images and style sheets.